# the KeyPressed method is not called when I push a game button

Tags: netbeans, java-me, lwuit

I added a `gameKeyListener()` to my `Form` for when the up and down `Button` is presed, but the `keyPressed()` method is not called.
My code:

```
    Form f = new Form();
         f.addGameKeyListener(Canvas.UP, this);
   f.addGameKeyListener(Canvas.DOWN, this);
          f.show();
}
    public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
       }

   public void keyPressed(int key)
{
   System.out.println ("Pressed");
    switch (key){
        case Canvas.DOWN:
            //code
            System.out.println ("Pressed");
            break;
        case Canvas.UP:
            //code
            System.out.println ("Pressed");
            break;
    }
}

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `addGameKeyListener` this fire action event. Try this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
switch (evt.getKeyEvent()){
        case Canvas.DOWN:
            //code
            System.out.println ("Pressed");
            break;
        case Canvas.UP:
            //code
            System.out.println ("Pressed");
            break;
    }
```

}

Comment: @frayab you win this time, but we will see again in the SO world

Answer (score 1):

You can see this post: [How to detect key pressed event in LWUIT form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818176/how-to-detect-key-pressed-event-in-lwuit-form/8821670#8821670)

I resolved it in this question

Comment: I ended up with the above posted code after reading the post you mention and I was still stuck with the problem.