# lwuit key released

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-textfield

How to detect key is released in Textfield ? I have tried by over-riding keyReleased(int code) but not working well . as shown in below :

```
TextField tf = new TextField(){

     public void keyReleased(int keyCode) {

                         }
                 };
```

Is there any idea?

Answer (score 1):

So, if you want to capture this key in a non-touch device, take a look on this post:

[LWUIT keyPressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818176/how-to-detect-key-pressed-event-in-lwuit-form)

If it is for touch devices, you may use the pointerReleased(int x, int y). Override it and do what you want to do inside this method.

Answer (score 1):

Override it in form. You should probably also state the device since not all devices act alike. You might want to use the `DataChangeListener` if you just want to track changes to the text field.

Comment: I have added the DAtaChangeListner to TextField and the problem is Only first character of keypad is passed even double/triple click on the same keypad. So I have over-ride on the keyReleased method on Textfield but unfortunately the problem is not solved.
So how can I solve it?

Comment: There was a special case for the first key in text fields. I think we resolved it in Codename One.